# limit data in aggregate function

Tags: r, aggregate, limit

Is there a way to limit the aggregated data?
An example:

```
aggregate(cars$speed, FUN=mean, by=list(cars$dist), data=cars)
```

gives exactly the same output as:

```
aggregate(cars$speed, FUN=mean, by=list(cars$dist), data=cars[cars$speed >= 15, ])
```

In this case there are only two variables but in my case I want to limit the data by a third variable. Is this possible within the aggregate function or is a new dataframe necessary?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The second one is more or less a typo. `aggregate(speed~dist, FUN=mean, data=cars[cars$speed >= 15, ])` is what you want.

Comment: or `aggregate(speed ~ dist, subset(cars, speed >= 15), mean)`

Comment: This helped me. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to ask a question about a dataset with three variables, it makes no sense to post an example that only uses 2.